# Dismiss Alert in React Native

Tags: react-native, alert

So I have an app that shows an alert when you go idle for a few seconds, and there is 'YES' button in the alert when you pressed it it will refresh the timer and shows the alert again, and if i do nothing with the alert it goes to next page somehow the Alert still open in the next page and I want it to be closed. Is there anyway to close it? Thanks in advance

here is my code

```js
componentDidMount(){
        this.timer = setTimeout(this.sessionTimeout, 3000); //auto reset after 60 seconds of inactivity
    }

    componentWillUnmount(){
        clearTimeout(this.timer);
    }

    sessionTimeout(){
        this.timer = setTimeout(this.onSubmit, 3000)
        Alert.alert('You ran out of time', 'still editing?',
        [
          {text: 'YES', onPress:this.resetTimer.bind(this)}
        ],
        {cancelable: false}
        ) 
    }

    resetTimer(){
        clearTimeout(this.timer);
        this.timer = setTimeout(this.sessionTimeout, 3000);
    }

onSubmit() {
        clearTimeout(this.timer);
        this.setState({ submitted: true }); //shows activity indicator

        const data = this.state;
        const result = validate(data, this.props.validationLang);

        if (!result.success) {
            this.setState({ error: result.error });
            this.setState({ submitted: false });     //terminate activity indicator
        }
        else
            this.props.onSubmit(this.extractData(data), () => this.setState({ submitted: false }));
    }
```

Comment: I suggest you use a custom alert box like a modal.

Comment: i'm not familiar with that, can you elaborate?

Comment: I'll write an answer...

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to close Alert so you can change the scenario of your navigation by setting up "No" button inside alert and navigate to another screen only after pressing no button without pressing any action it should stay on this screen you can set button name to any thing instead of "No" which make sense to user then i can navigate to other screen if i don't want to refresh the timer by pressing yes.

Answer (score 2):

You reset when the alert appears, you press `OK`, you press `No`, you want the screen to move.

```js
       Alert.alert('You ran out of time', 'still editing?',
        [
          {text: 'YES', onPress: () => this.resetTimer()},
                {
                  text: "Cancel",
                  onPress: () => this.props.navigation.navigate("nextScreen"),
                  style: "cancel"
                }
        ],
        {cancelable: false}
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [react-native-modalbox](https://github.com/maxs15/react-native-modalbox) like this:

```
    modal = null;

    render(){
       return (
         <Modal
           ref={(ref) => { this.modal = ref }}
           coverScreen={true}
           position={"center"}
           onClosed={() => { console.log('modal closed') }}
           swipeToClose={true} 
           backdropPressToClose={true} >
           <View>
              <Text>Message</Text>
              <TouchableOpacity 
                  onPress={() => { this.modal.close() }}
              >
                  <Text>close</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
           </View>
         </Modal>
       )
   }
```

Now you can show modal with `this.modal.open()` and close it with `this.modal.open()` and track closing modal with props of your Modal component.
For more information please read the [Documentation](https://github.com/maxs15/react-native-modalbox).

I hope this can helo you.

Comment: how do implement it with setTimeout ?

Comment: you can call `this.modal.open()` and after 3 seconds, call `this.modal.close()` and go to next page.